# Index data from multiple table into solr

Tags: mysql, solr

I have three table TableA,TableB and TableC

**TableA**

idA ------------ PK
col1A

**TableB**
idB ----------- PK
col1B

**TableC**
idC ---------- PK
col1C

I am indexing all the data in **solr** in single core there may be a chance of overriding    **TableC** data with **TableB** or **TableA** and Vice versa. Because the primary key are auto generated and there is a possibility of having same value in different tables. How do I solve this problem.

I have two solutions.
1) I was thinking of appending a suffix pk_tablename to make the unique id in **solr**.

2) create separate core for each table.

which do you suggest is the best ?
In my business domain the table can have millions of records.

please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 should be fine. You can store data from different tables in a single core if you want to search them all with a single query. Your primary key is fine. Along with that you can also store the table name in another field, so your docs will look like:

```
{
  unique_id: 1234_A,
  id: 1234,
  table: A,
  data: <text field>
}
```

Storing the table name will help you perform searches restricted to some table(s) only.